# Running Blender off of network drive

Tags: game-engine, network

I need to run a BGE executable off of a network drive. I can not install or run any problems off of the computer. The network drive is also quite slow.

My Questions:

Does the blender executable depend on any DLLs or any thing that isn't already included in the folder below?

Can anyone confirm that the files in the folder below are all that the simulator.exe should need to run? (These files were created when I exported as a BGE executable)
[image: folder on network drive with executable]

Is there any reason that a Blender executable wouldn't like being run off of a network drive? The program runs well off of a USB.

This is the error I get when I try to run the above simulator.exe file

[image]

Comment: There is no need to install blender on the computer. If you download the Zip version and unpack it, you should be able to run it from the directory that contains it. As an alternative, maybe you can run it out of a USB drive?

Comment: This is fine to work on any windows system.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the following worked on my own shared drive, both PCs running Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit:

**1. in the sharing settings for that particular folder, make sure that Read AND write are enabled:**

[image]

**2. Make sure your antivirus and firewall allow the exe to run (In my case, Avast was blocking it)**

**3. make sure that "Run as Administrator" is enabled in the exe properties:**

[image]